# jQuery variable substitution

Tags: jquery, user-interface

I have a simple jQuery function below.. I'm interested in dynamically changing the 'query:FOOTBALL' attribute with a dynamic page variable. So something like 'query:PAGE_TITLE' or PAGE_VAR

I haven't had any luck get .replace() to work.. I must be overlooking something very simple; What approach do you all take here?

```
  jQuery(function($){
      $("#query").tweet({
        avatar_size: 32,
        count: 4,
        query: "FOOTBALL",
        loading_text: "searching twitter..."
      });
  });
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'm not exactly clear on what you're asking, but I think you want to use a variable instead of a string literal... As `query` is expecting a String, you can use any String value there. So  if you have a variable called `myVar` containing a string, you can use `myVar` in place of the string literal:

```
var myVar = "Some String";
jQuery(function($){
  $("#query").tweet({
    avatar_size: 32,
    count: 4,
    query: myVar,
    loading_text: "searching twitter..."
  });
});
```

Or, you could do something like this to use the value entered into an `input` by the user:

```
jQuery(function($){
  $("#query").tweet({
    avatar_size: 32,
    count: 4,
    query: $("#someInput").val(), //val() returns a string so it will work here
    loading_text: "searching twitter..."
  });
});
```

Answer (score 0):

Just stuff it in a variable, then pass along. The page will have already loaded so you can grab the text from any element you'd like with jQuery.

```
jQuery(function($){
    // maybe you want the <title> tag value
    var query = location.title; 
    // or maybe the text from the first <h1>
    //query = $('h1:first').text(); 

    $("#query").tweet({
        avatar_size: 32,
        count: 4,
        query: query,
        loading_text: "searching twitter..."
    });
});
```